# gitlab CLI - get project variable value

Tags: python, gitlab, command-line-interface, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I am basically trying to do this

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('git.mygit.com', private_token='my_token')
gl.projects.get(ID).variables.get('KEY').value
```

but using CLI commands. I can get to the correct variable, but cannot access the value

```
gitlab project-variable get --project-id ID --key KEY
```

I noticed there is `--value` option in the documentation of `gitlab project-variable create`, but I can't find a way to access the value of already set project variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the output type (example: json):

```
 gitlab -o json project-variable get --project-id ID --key KEY
```